# Erro com validação personalizada com express-validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, validação

Estou tentando fazer uma validação personalizada com o *express-validator* que deve retornar uma mensagem de erro caso o valor seja diferente de `null` e tenha o valor diferente de `10` caracteres, e que deve retornar `true` caso o valor seja `null` ou tenha `10` caracteres.

A mensagem de erro funciona, porém mesmo passando o valor de maneira correta ainda chega uma mensagem de erro dizendo que o valor é inválido, e quando eu coloco o return `true` na minha validação personalizada ou passo o valor `null` em vez de uma *string*, a requisição só carrega e não retorna nada.

Minha validação personalizada:

```
body("dataVenda").custom((value) => {
    if(value !== null && value.length !== 10){
        return Promise.reject("Preencha o campo data de venda de forma correta");
    }
    return true;
 }).optional({nullable: true})
```

Esse é o modo que estou passando o dado:

```
{
  "dataVenda": "27/08/2021"
}
```

E essa é a mensagem de erro quando passo o valor de maneira correta contendo os `10` caracteres:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "value": "27/08/2021",
      "msg": "Invalid value",
      "param": "dataVenda",
      "location": "body"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto seria fazer a validação utilizando o próprio express-validator e o encadeamento de expressões para fazer a validação que deseja.

Desta forma podemos utilizar o a função [`optional`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#optionaloptions) com parâmetro *nullable* (que já está utilizando) em conjunto com a função `isLength` passando o parâmetro *min* e *max*.

Segue um exemplo:

```
body('dataVenda').optional({nullable: true}).isLength({min: 10, max: 10})
```

Para aprender mais sobre o express-validator utilize a [documentação oficial](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/)

Comment: Acabei de editar meu código e está funcionando perfeitamente, muito obrigado!